# Is there any way to put non AES-NI processors to use for mining?

Tags: cpu-mining

Is there anyway to use non AES-NI processors for mining Monero or is it mostly just a waste of time because the hashrate is so small?

Comment: It's mostly just a waste of time and electricity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. You just have to set **./configure --disable-aes-ni** when building  [the cpu miner](https://github.com/wolf9466/cpuminer-multi). 
There is a memory leak when built without aes-ni. So you will have to restart it regularly (for me, that was at least once every 2 days).

With a pretty good [core 2 duo](http://ark.intel.com/products/33910/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8400-6M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB), i get ~30 h/s (both core running) for ~100 Watt. So, unless you have a little army of them and free electricity, it is not worth it.

Comment: No need to use that obsolete CPU miner. I merged the CPU miner code into the GPU miner, and it auto-detects AES NI so you don't need to change the build flags. https://github.com/wolf9466/wolf-xmr-miner/commit/fc3a218d7250d67f8199ff56d1af24eec7bcb6a0

Comment: Is this method also useful for compiling any of the coin daemons for similar processors?

Comment: @hyc Did you make [`hyc/cpuminer-multi`](https://github.com/hyc/cpuminer-multi)?  It gave me `CPU does not have AES-NI, which is required`.  When I tried it with `--disable-aes-ni`, it wouldn't compile.